# Grouping Table rows using array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good Day,
I have table of sample following data

```
ID  Date         Loc  Time From  Time To
1   01-jan-2018  10   08:15      17:00
1   02-jan-2018  10   08:15      17:00
**1   03-jan-2018  10   08:15      09:00
1   03-jan-2018  20   09:15      11:30
1   03-jan-2018  30   11:45      14:00
1   03-jan-2018  10   14:15      17:00**
1   04-jan-2018  10   08:15      17:00
```

In this table I wanted to group records of same Date such that following was the output:

```
ID  Date         Loc  Time From  Time To
1   01-jan-2018  10   08:15      17:00
1   02-jan-2018  10   08:15      17:00
**1   03-jan-2018  10   08:15      17:00**
1   03-jan-2018  10   08:15      09:00
1   03-jan-2018  20   09:15      11:30
1   03-jan-2018  30   11:45      14:00
1   03-jan-2018  10   14:15      17:00
1   04-jan-2018  10   08:15      17:00
```

Grouping was achieved using below question:

[Grouping table rows based on cell value using jquery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962725/grouping-table-rows-based-on-cell-value-using-jquery-javascript)

But in order to achieve the summary row at the top of the group I was using the approach to get the first row of the group make a copy modify it for summary then add it at the start of group through two different approaches showing in following code:

```
for (var id in rowGroups) {
  var group = rowGroups[id];
  // Loop through and add header rows to rowgroups
  if (group.length > 1)
  {
    /*  // Method # 1 using Array assignment
    var rowmain = group.slice(0);
    rowmain.cells[2].innerText = "";
    rowmain.cells[3].innerText = group[0].cells[3].innerText;
    rowmain.cells[4].innerText = group[group.length - 1].cells[4].innerText;
    */

    /*
    var rowmain = $(group)[0];
    $($(rowmain)[0]).find('td')[2].innerText = "";  // Location
    $($(rowmain)[0]).find('td')[3].innerText = group[0].cells[3].innerText;
    $($(rowmain)[0]).find('td')[4].innerText = group[group.length - 1].cells[4].innerText;
    */
    group.unshift(rowmain)
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < group.length; j++) {
    var row = group[j];
    if (group.length > 1 && j == 1) {
      row.className = 'subrow';
    }
    if (group.length > 1 && j == 0) {
      var firstCell = row.cells[0];
      $("<span class='collapsed'>").appendTo(firstCell).click(plusClick);
    }
    table.tBodies[0].appendChild(row);
  }
}
```

But it seems that javascript array is used as reference so in each case when I pick the first row of group (array element) and modify the copy it also changes the original. Please help how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: "*But it seems that javascript array is used as reference…*". Yes. All objects are referenced, so `var group = rowGroups[id]` creates a second reference to the object. Perhaps you want to copy it: `var group = rowGroups[id].slice()`.

Comment: I have used slice in my first approach `var rowmain = group.slice(0);`

Comment: I don't understand your example, what is the **? And a row has values but you just move the cell `17:00` to the second row without moving the other rows.  Do you want to sort rows by a certain column?

Comment: No, I was trying to make the row bold by `**`, What i want to do is create a row group for 03-Jan-2018, add a summary row at the top of the group and then then make the rows as sub row. the sub row part is working through the link I mentioned, but I cant get the summary row.

Comment: It would help if you post a [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a runnable snippet.